# Google Search in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any plugin or possibility to add google search in flutter app? There will be a button with text. If user clicks that button it will take that text and go to browser and search in google. In html it's like this:

```html
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search"> 
<div style="border:1px solid black;padding:4px;width:20em;"> <table border="0" cellpadding="0"> 
<tr>
<td> 
<input type="text" name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
</td>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
</form>
```

How to implement this in flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) plugin. To search for a specific thing, append a [query parameter](https://moz.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-google-search-parameters) to the google url, e.g.: `https://www.google.com/search?q=query+goes+here`